# File does not exist: /htdocs

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, linux

I just fired a new amazon ec2 instance and i followed these [directions](http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/ubuntu/howto-install-apache-php-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/1027/) and i get this when i visit the [site](http://ec2-50-17-12-246.compute-1.amazonaws.com/)

```
  File does not exist: /htdocs
```

also how do i get the elastic ip for this server because on the amazon console its blank

i cant tell what kind of ubuntu this is ..i see this

```
 Linux domU-12-31-39-02-5D-E7 2.6.31-302-ec2 #7-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 13 19:06:04 UTC 2009 i686
```

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
> ```

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

 Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
     </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you please post content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`?

Comment: posted in my original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

figured out it was just that i forgot to enable the defualt vhost

```
 a2ensite default
```